# sharpPDF , how to create text with background color?

Tags: c#, pdf

I needed to create some PDF document , that can set background color of text , so i checked sharppdf library and the doc:  [Sharp PDF doc](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/Tutorials.html) , but it doesn't seem to support this feature.

Did i miss something or is there any other library that can fit my reqirements ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the same roadblock some months ago.  We found that most of the dynamic pdf creators were lacking in one way or another (some didn't render css properly, others just produced sh*tty-looking outputs, etc).

Enter [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), probably the absolute best (pd)effing tool on the planet.  It's free, it's fast, and it turns html-based input into immaculate pdf's.  In fact, we loved it so much that we started using it for most of our pdf'ing needs.  Of course, the one caveat is that you're limited to pdf'ing files that can be rendered by webkit-based browsers (html, txt, etc).  I don't know what kind of files you need to pdf, but office docs can be saved as HTML nowadays.  I would highly, highly recommend that program.

PS - I just re-read my post and realized I sound like a total fanboy -- I am not a fanboy...just a very, very happy customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
have you tried a google search outside of the doc..?
```

If it comes with an example folder which I am sure it does.. look at OverLay example or Water Mark example